# TabHost do not match is parent width in HoneyComb Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-tabhost, fill-parent

I'm trying to make a TabHost on HoneyComb as if I was on 1.6+ but the fact is when I copy the code (which is the same for both HoneyComb and previous version), the TabHost do not match the screen width. I don't get it?

Using Halo theme on API 3.0 with the emulator.

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</TabHost>
```

And here is my Activity :

```
package org.agetac;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class TabsActivity extends TabActivity {

    private static final String TAB_SITAC = "tab_sitac";
    private static final String TAB_SOEI = "tab_soei";
    private static final String TAB_MOYEN = "tab_moyen";
    private static final String TAB_TAB4 = "tab_tab4";
    private static final String TAB_TAB5 = "tab_tab5";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

        TabHost tHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent tabIntent;


        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        tabIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, SITACActivity.class);
        spec = tHost.newTabSpec(TAB_SITAC).setIndicator(getString(R.string.sitac),
                          getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_sitac))
                      .setContent(tabIntent);
        tHost.addTab(spec);

        tabIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, SOEIActivity.class);
        spec = tHost.newTabSpec(TAB_SOEI).setIndicator(getString(R.string.soei),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_soei))
            .setContent(tabIntent);
        tHost.addTab(spec);

        tabIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, MoyenActivity.class);
        spec = tHost.newTabSpec(TAB_MOYEN).setIndicator(getString(R.string.moyen),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_moyen))
            .setContent(tabIntent);
        tHost.addTab(spec);

        tabIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab4Activity.class);
        spec = tHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAB4).setIndicator(getString(R.string.tab4),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_tab4))
            .setContent(tabIntent);
        tHost.addTab(spec);

        tabIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab5Activity.class);
        spec = tHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAB5).setIndicator(getString(R.string.tab5),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_tab5))
            .setContent(tabIntent);
        tHost.addTab(spec);

        tHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why does TabHost behave like that with HoneyComb?

Comment: That's what I get on the tablet emulator
[Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/capturedu20111117135437.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats normal behaviour and how it's planned by Google. The Tabs won't fill the whole Activity unless you write your own TabHost.